# Why is my image not loading even though the code is correct?

Tags: css, reactjs

there is no compile errors and my pages load. However, my images don't display when they're called using CSS. Example below. From doing research, I saw something about a web pack but I tried to install file loader NPM and it didn't work. Thank you!

[No compile errors][1]
,kmkmmk

Comment: Did you debug? You could look from where the img gets loaded, and what its content is when you are using it inside your webpage, might even look inside the network tab

Comment: Good idea, I will look into that now thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try just importing it instead?

Heres an example you might be able to use for your content array:

https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-ellis-qitz4?file=/src/App.js

```js
import img from "./img/img.jpg"
//const img = require("./img/img.jpg")
const App = () => {
  return  (
    <Img src={img} alt={alt} />
  )

}
```

Or try this:

```js
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const content = [
  {
    BGLight: false,
    lightTopLine: true,
    TextPoint: true,
    TitleMain: "SECURE APP",
    description:
      "Group 35’s project works towards solving the zero hunger owards solving the zero hunger SGGS because, our group ",
    img: require("./img/img1.jpg"),
    alt: "img",
    TextPointDesc: true
  },
  {
    BGLight: false,
    lightTopLine: true,
    TextPoint: true,
    TitleMain: "SECURE APP",
    description:
      "Group 35’s project works towards solving the zero hunger owards solving the zero hunger SGGS because, our group  ",
    img: require("./img/img2.jpg"),
    alt: "img",
    TextPointDesc: true
  },
  {
    BGLight: false,
    lightTopLine: true,
    TextPoint: true,
    TitleMain: "SECURE APP",
    description:
      "Group 35’s project works towards solving the zero   ",
    img: require("./img/img3.jpg"),
    alt: "img",
    TextPointDesc: true
  }
];

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div style={{ height: "100vh", width: "100vw" }}>
      {content.map((c) => {
        const image = c.img;
        return <img style={{ height: "100vh", width: "100vw" }} src={image} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

This would work if you didnt know the exact name:

```js
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const content = [
  {
    BGLight: false,
    lightTopLine: true,
    TextPoint: true,
    TitleMain: "SECURE APP",
    description:
      "Group 35’s project works towards solving the zero gry and missing meals.  ",
    alt: "img",
    TextPointDesc: true
  },
  {
    BGLight: false,
    lightTopLine: true,
    TextPoint: true,
    TitleMain: "SECURE APP",
    description:
      "Group 35’s project works towards solving the zero  tool, homeless people will have an increased chance in not going hungry and missing meals.  ",
    alt: "img",
    TextPointDesc: true
  },
  {
    BGLight: false,
    lightTopLine: true,
    TextPoint: true,
    TitleMain: "SECURE APP",
    description:
      "Group 35’s project works towards solving the zero  have an increased chance in not going hungry and missing meals.  ",
    alt: "img",
    TextPointDesc: true
  }
];

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div style={{ height: "100vh", width: "100vw" }}>
      {content.map((c, cIndex) => {
        const image = require(`./img/img${cIndex + 1}.jpg`);
        return <img style={{ height: "100vh", width: "100vw" }} src={image} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Good idea, but I'm using a react reusable component and the way I set it up I can't do that. I added something in the post if you can think of a way how to incorporate that into the CSS. Thanks

Comment: Most likely not CSS, but since your data is coming from js, the image would need to be required from the component. Try this: https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-ellis-qitz4?file=/src/App.js Another note, i couldnt get the images to load with .default.

Comment: Thank you so much!   removing the .default made it work. You put so much effort into that answer. Thank you so much! Stay safe during these covid times. Once again, thank you so much!

Comment: @TAKINGXPTAKINGXP You too :) I also just added a more dynamic option!